# Node.js forEach into array

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

I am trying to query the master server which returns the result in this format:

```
[
    { ip: '127.0.0.1', port: 28961 },
    { ip: '127.0.0.1', port: 28965 }
]
```

Then, I need to query every server and it's IP with queryDedicated which then returns the data in a callback (same as queryMaster).

If the returned data in the callback is valid, it will add it to an array, and finally print the whole servers array to the console.

```
var servers = {};

function blabla(host, port) {
    queryMaster(host, port, function(data) {
       async.forEach(data, function(key, next) {
            queryDedicated(key.ip, key.port, function(srv) {
                if (srv) {
                    // if callback data valid, add to array
                    servers[key.ip + ':' + key.port] = srv;
                }
            })

            // valid or not, continue
            next();
        }, function(err) {
            // print servers array
            console.log(servers);
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that my servers array is empty.

Final 'servers' array should output the data in this format:

```
{
    "176.57.141.60:28960": {
        "hostname": "board.landstuhl-atzel.de Schlachthaus #1",
        "address": "176.57.141.60:28960",
        "gametype": "war",
        "mapname": "mp_rundown",
        "players": "0",
        "max_players": "18"
    },
    "176.57.142.144:28663": {
        "hostname": "ClassicSnD.org No mercy for hackers. No lag. No bullshit. [B3]",
        "address": "176.57.142.144:28663",
        "gametype": "sd",
        "mapname": "mp_favela",
        "players": "0",
        "max_players": "18"
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you're calling `next()` synchronously. You need to go with the async `queryDedicated` callback!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I assume that you are using the [`async` module](https://github.com/caolan/async).

### With `async`

While the forEach function can work, I would recommend to try with the [`reduce`](https://github.com/caolan/async#reduce) function of async:

```
  function blabla(host, port) {
    queryMaster(host, port, function(data) {
       async.reduce(data, {}, function(memo, item, next){
          queryDedicated(item.ip, item.port, function(srv) {
            if (srv) {
              memo[item.ip+':'+item.port] = srv;
            }
            // valid or not, continue
            next(null, memo);
          });
     }, function(err, result) {
        // print servers array
        console.log(result);
      });
    });
  }
```

Instead of having a global `servers` object, you can pass a memo as an empty object: in case you still want the global object, just pass the `servers` variable as a memo.

### Alternative solution with vanilla JS

```
// simple "parallel" async iterator
function asyncIterator(array, callback, lastCallback){
  var completed = 0;
  array.forEach(function(item){
    callback(item, end);
  });
  function end(){
    completed += 1;
    if(completed >= array.length){
      lastCallback();
    }
  }
}

var servers = {};

function blabla(host, port) {
  queryMaster(host, port, function(data) {
     asyncIterator(data, function(item, next){
       queryDedicated(item.ip, item.port, function(srv) {
          if (srv) {
            servers[item.ip+':'+item.port] = srv;
          }
          // valid or not, continue
          next();
        });
   }, function() {
      // print servers array
      console.log(servers);
    });
  });
}
```

Note that this vanilla solution is pretty simple: the iterator doesn't take in account input validation, or errors.
If you are planning to use many `async` calls I would recommend the library above which will make easier your life.

Comment: console.log(result); returns {} but srv outputs what it should

Comment: You're sure that `srv` is not null in the callback? What if you log it?

Comment: I have console.log(srv); right after memo[item.ip+':'+item.port] = srv;

Comment: Sure! Sorry, I'll fix it: the callback was returning before the `queryDedicated` was performed - I guess it is an async call!

Comment: Of course there is a solution without it, but I thought you were using it in your code - the `async` var in you code. Give me a sec to post the alternative.